# What is the equivalent of GDB's "define" in PDB?

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, pdb

I use python debugger PDB as a script debugger. I would like to define a PDB function that runs 2 commands at the same time (for instance, print variable value and go to next line). Debugging C code using GDB I would do this:

```
(gdb) def f
Type commands for definition of "f".
End with a line saying just "end".
>p i
>n
>end
(gdb) f
```

But trying the same with PDB doesn't work:

```
(Pdb) def f
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way to do it?